# Extending a convex function to a higher dimensional domain

Tags: convex-analysis, mean-value-theorem

Let $D\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ be the unit disk, and $I=(-1,1)$.

Let $v\in C^2(\bar I)$ be a convex function.

> Does there exist a convex function $u\in C^2(\bar D)$, such that on the one hand $u(\cdot,0)=v$, and on the other hand
> $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{\partial D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}d\ell\le \frac{v'(1)-v'(-1)}2\quad ?$$
> In other words, the average value of the outer normal derivative of $u$ is less than or equal to that of $v$.

The answer is positive if $v$ is even: just take $u(x)=v(\|x\|)$.

**Edit.** Christian's answer tells us that the inequality above is true, but not sharp: one has
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{\partial D}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}d\ell\le c(v'(1)-v'(-1))$$
with $c=\frac1\pi$. Whence the additional **question**:

> What is the smallest constant $c$ with the property above (existence of a convex extension such that the inequality occurs) ?

Comment: Concerning your [edit](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/463223/revisions), I would like to draw your attention to the following: (i) as is now made explicit, the same coefficient $c=\frac1\pi$ of course obtains in my answer and (ii) according to [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer), there should be only one question in one post.

Comment: Do you have a response to my comment and the answers on this page?

Answer (score 5):

Yes: Just take $u(x,y):=v(x)$, which will be assumed in what follows.

Indeed, one can use Green's formula to show this, as is done in [Christian Remling's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/463229/36721).

More generally, the result holds for any convex function $v$, without requiring it to be in $C^2$ -- of course, if $u$ is not required to be in $C^2$ and if the derivative $v'(x)$ is understood as (say) the right derivative of $v$ at $x$ for $x\in[-1,1)$ (and the left derivative for $x=1$).

Indeed, with $u(x,y):=v(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$, the inequality in question is invariant with respect to taking positive/conical mixtures of functions $v$. That is, if the inequality in question holds for each suitably integrable function $v_b$ (in place of $v$) with $b$ in a set $B$, then the inequality in question holds for the positive mixture (used in place of $v$) of the form $\int_B\mu(db)\,v_b$ of the $v_b$'s, where $\mu$ is any nonnegative measure over $B$ such that the integral $\int_B\mu(db)\,v_b$ exists in a suitable sense.

It remains to note that the convex function $v$ is a positive mixture of affine functions and the functions of the form $v_a$ with $a\in(-1,1)$, where $v_a(x):=\max(0,x-a)$, and for any one of these latter functions the inequality in question is straightforward to check.

In fact, the constant factor $\frac12$ in the upper bound $\frac12\,(v'(1)-v'(-1))$ can be replaced by the better factor $\frac1\pi$ -- because for affine functions in place of $v$ one can replace $\frac12$ by $0$, and for $v=v_a$ with $a\in(-1,1)$ can replace $\frac12$ by $\frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\pi$. So, the worst case here is that of $v_a$ with $a=0$.

---

**Detail:** The mentioned mixture representation of the convex function $v$ is as follows: for $x\in(-1,1)$,
$$\begin{aligned}
&v(x) \\ 
&=v(-1+)+\int_{[-1,x)}dz\,v'(z) \\ 
&=v(-1+)+\int_{[-1,1)}dz\,1(z<x)\,v'(z) \\ 
&=v(-1+)+\int_{[-1,1)}dz\,1(z<x)\,\Big(v'(-1)+\int_{[-1,z]}\,dv'(a)\Big) \\ 
&=v(-1+)+v'(-1)(x+1) \\ 
&\qquad\qquad+\int_{[-1,1)}dz\,1(z<x)\,\int_{[-1,z]}\,dv'(a) \\ 
&=v(-1+)+v'(-1)(x+1) \\ 
&\qquad\qquad+\int_{[-1,1)}\,dv'(a)\int_{[-1,1)}dz\,1(a\le z<x)\, \\ 
&=[v(-1+)+v'(-1)]+v'(-1)x+\int_{[-1,1)}\,dv'(a)\,v_a(x) \\  
&=[v(-1+)+v'(-1)]+v'(-1)x+\int_{[-1,1)}\,\mu_{v'}(da)\,v_a(x) \\  
\end{aligned}$$
where $\mu_{v'}$ is the (nonnegative) Lebesgue--Stieltjes measure corresponding to the nondecreasing function $v'$. So,
$$v=C+A\,\text{id}+\int_{[-1,1)}\,\mu_{v'}(da)\,v_a,  $$
where $C:=C_v:=v(-1+)+v'(-1)$ and $A:=A_v:=v'(-1)$ are real numbers, and $\text{id}$ is the identity function.

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "$v$ is a mixture of..."?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : I have now done this.

Answer (score 4):

$u(x,y)=v(x)$ works. By [Green's formula,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Theorem) we can rewrite the LHS of your inequality as
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\!\!\!\int \Delta u\, dA = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1}^1 dy\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} dx\,v''(x) \le \frac{1}{\pi}(v'(1)-v'(-1)).
$$

Comment: The same answer, at about the same time. :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Yes, and from your answer I now realize that no calculation was needed...